# How do I remove an element from a list without using .remove

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that finds the minimum value of a list and removes it, only without using .remove or min.  I have the code to find the minimum value:

```
userlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
smallest = userlist[0]
def removeMin():
  for i in range(1, len(userlist)):
    if userlist[i] < smallest:
        smallest = userlist[i]
```

I've tried using .pop but clearly that does not work because smallest is a variable and not a position.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a puzzle?  Any reason not to use `.remove`?  Or are you trying to implement a priority queue?

Comment: Find the position of smallest value and then pop it as pop takes an argument which decides which one to pop.

Comment: @RayToal if it was puzzle, the correct answer is: `userlist.pop(userlist.index(-max([-u for u in userlist])))`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Very nice, I especially like the simulation of `min` with `max` + the comprehension.  I'm still puzzled by the question, though.  `pop` is very similar to `remove` and finding the smallest value by index vs. by value doesn't seem like a big deal.  It would be nice to know the source of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating through a python object, there are much better ways to iterate than using range. Any iterable can be looped through like so:

```
for x in my_list:
   pass # do something
```

The above will step through every element set the current iteration to `x`. However, if you want the index as well, use the Python [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in, which instead of giving just the item, also gives the current index, like so:

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
   pass # do something
```

So for your function you want something like:

```
def removeMin(my_list):
  smallestIndex = 0
  smallest = my_list[0]
  for i,val in enumerate(my_list):
    if val < smallest:
        smallest = val
        smallestIndex = i
  my_list.pop(smallestIndex)
  return my_list
```

---

edit: if it is a puzzle, the most devious way of doing it is with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like so:

```
userlist.pop(userlist.index(-max([-u for u in userlist])))
```

This:

- creates a list comprehension, which inverts the list: `[-u for u in userlist]`
- finds the `max`imum of that list (which is the minimum of the normal list) `max(...)`
- finds in the original list the index of the first element with the value of the negative of the maximum  `userlist.index(-...)`
- and finally pops that element `userlist.pop(...)`

Voila, not a `.remove` or a `min` in sight!

Comment: unless I'm missing something couldn't you replace `max([-u for u in userlist])` with `min(userlist)`?

Comment: @GP89 one of the two requirements was that the op couldn't use `min`.

Comment: Oops haha. I guess i skim read the text. I missed the min part. I did think it was a bit odd :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one straight forward approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

userlist = [10,2,30,4,5]
def rm_min(lis):
    minn = None
    ind = None
    for i, j in enumerate(lis):
        if minn and j < minn:
            minn = j
            ind = i
        elif not minn:
            minn = j
        else:
            pass
    return [ y for x,y in enumerate(userlist) if x != ind]

print rm_min(userlist)
```

Output:

[10, 30, 4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your main task is merely supposed to find out and remove the smallest item in a certain list, **I mean not care about the order of those elements**. Maybe you can try python's `heapq` module.

It provides an implementation that transforms list into a heap, **in-place**. Then you can remove the smallest element of the heap in a simple and efficient way:

Here is a sample:

```
import heapq

#alist could be a disordered list, it doesn't matter
alist = [10, 2, 4, 5, 8, 50]

heapq.heapify(alist)   #transform alist to heap, in-place. That means None is returned

smallest = heapq.heappop(alist)  #pop the smallest element of alist, here is 2

print smallest  #output: 2
```

And you can simply go on, to find out and remove the 2nd small(3rd small, 4th small, ...) element of the remaining `alist`, using `heapq.heappop(alist)`, until an `IndexError` raised(nothing left in alist):

```
print heapq.heappop(alist)  #output: 4

print heapq.heappop(alist)   #output: 5

print heapq.heappop(alist)   #output: 8

print heapq.heappop(alist)   #output: 10

print heapq.heappop(alist)   #output: 50
```

If continue... `IndexError` raised:

```
In [7]: heapq.heappop(alist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/chiyu/<ipython-input-7-8faac314c419> in <module>()
----> 1 heapq.heappop(alist)

IndexError: index out of range

In [8]:
```

You can put the `heappop` into a `try/except` block:

```
import heapq

alist = [10, 2, 4, 5, 8, 50]

heapq.heapify(alist)

while True:
    try:
        smallest = heapq.heappop(alist)
    except IndexError:
        break

    print smallest
```

The output would be:

```
2
4
5
8
10
50
```

**There's one thing deserved to be mentioned again:**

- **if you really care about the order of the elements in the given list,
  heapq would be unsuitable.**

Because when you call `heapq.heapify(alist)` orders of those elements have changed:

```
In [8]: alist = [10, 2, 4, 5, 8, 50]

In [9]: heapq.heapify(alist)

In [10]: alist
Out[10]: [2, 5, 4, 10, 8, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple approach without any complex loops and functions

```
arr=[1,20,5,78,30]
    count=0
    element=int(input("enter the element you want to remove:"))
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if(arr[i]==element):
            count=count+1
    if(count>=1):
        pos=arr.index(element)
        arr1 = arr[:pos]+arr[pos+1:]
        print(arr1)
    else:
        print("element not found in array")
```